# What does the error message "Mailbox is awaiting JIT provisioning" mean in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I get this message when I query the API for messages on some mailboxes in my organization.  It sounds like it's a temporary situation that will be fixed over time, unlike other messages like 400/not found or invalid licenses.  Couldn't find any information to confirm/deny this speculation.  Is it a temporary situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in code. For users that don't have mailboxes in O365 cloud, sometimes instead of returning 404, the service ends up returning 503 or 500 with this error. You can safely ignore this error and treat this as a 404 mailbox not found.